# Sorting objects by class type or class name within a collection data structur

Tags: java, sorting, object

I'm new to Java but not to basic programming.  Because of this, I have not yet fully learned all of the terms and their meaning.  With that being said, I may not be describing what I want so I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I am writing an abstract parent class Status which will parent subclasses such as (Buff) and (Debuff) which will most likely be abstract as well.  Suffice to say that eventually I will be writing concrete classes with their own class names that inherit, in some way, from Status.

The idea is to iterate through a list of these objects and have them modify another Dragon.object.  The order becomes important though because these Status objects mathematically modify values in another class of objects.  Because of this and the fact that there is no order that these objects will be instantiated, I would end up with unintended results when one Status increases a value by 10% and another subtracts 5 from that value.

The reason I provide this background is because I'm not sure that I am approaching this problem correctly and hope that if I am going down the wrong path, someone can correct me here.

On to my question; it seems easy enough to compare objects by a value in one of their fields.  Does this hold true for class types as well?  If so, how would I write a comparator that compares object types.  By "object types", i mean;

compare: Status.Buff.Percentage.Strength10Percent to Status.Buff.Additive.Strength10

Should I just place a field in this class that designates it's priority and then use a custom comparator when sorting or is the object type enough (provided Java can do that)?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're taking the wrong approach to the design. What you're trying to do is calculate modifiers for an RPG, right? If that's the case, you should have them all instantiate an interface with an `apply(Character c)` method, which encapsulates the modification and applies it to the character (or robot or whatever you're applying the modifiers to). The `Character` should implement an interface which has getters and setters for the attributes you want to modify, so that `apply()` can make adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare by something they both have, i.e some field in `Buff` or `Status`, it is possible. You can have a non-abstract compareTo-method in `Buff` or `Status` in that case (make sure the class `implements Comparable`). As the sub-classes inherit from `Buff` or `Status`, the same `compareTo()` method will be called from the children, unless they override it (which shouldn't be done then, really).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a priority field.

Having said that, you can either use `this.getClass().getName()` to get the name of the current class if that is enough for you to find the priority. You can then use the class name in the compareTo method.

You can also use `instanceof` to check if a particular object is an object of a subclass of a particular class. For example, refering back to your example:

An object of `Status.Buff.Percentage.Strength10Percent` will return true for:

`obj instanceof Percentage`

or

`obj instanceof Buff`